# como obter o elemento de uma lista baseada em outra lista

Tags: python, lista

Queria tirar um dúvida que estou tendo com listas em Python, segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
lista1 = [2, -1 , 4, -5]  
lista2 = [1, 2, 4, 9]
```

A medida que o elemento da lista1 seja > 0, eu preciso pegar o elemento da lista1 e lista2 na mesma posição, e adicionar ambos em lista diferentes, alguém pode me ajudar?

As saídas esperadas para o exemplo são as listas `[2, 4]`, que são os valores positivos em `lista1`, e `[1, 4]` que são os respectivos valores em `lista2`.

Comment: Qual seria o resultado esperado para esse exemplo?

Comment: novaLista1 = [2, 4] e novaLista2 = [1, 4]

A medida que o elemento da lista1 é positivo, eu pego o elemento da lista1 e lista2 na mesma posição e adiciono em listas diferentes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, você precisa definir sua estrutura de filtro, para definir quais posições permanecerão na lista e quais serão removidas. Para tal, basta criar uma lista que possui `True` nas posições em que o valor em `lista1` é positivo e `False` caso contrário.

```
filtro = [valor1 > 0 for valor1 in lista1]
```

Isso gerará a lista `[True, False, True, False]` indicando o que permanece e o que sairá.

> **Nota:** aqui é importante que `filtro` seja uma lista (e não um gerador), pois mais abaixo ele será consumido mais de uma vez (gerador não permitirá isso).

A partir disso basta utilizar a função `itertools.compress`:

```
from itertools import compress

nova_lista1 = list(compress(lista1, filtro))
nova_lista2 = list(compress(lista2, filtro))
```

Assim, `nova_lista1` será `[2, 4]` e `nova_lista2` será `[1, 4]`.

A própria função `compress` retorna um objeto iterável, então se não precisar de todos os valores em memória poderá utilizar o próprio retorno ao invés de gerar uma nova lista (propriamente dita).

De uma forma muito mais iterativa, você poderia percorrer as duas listas gerando as novas quando a condição for satisfeita:

```
lista1 = [2, -1 , 4, -5]  
lista2 = [1, 2, 4, 9]  

nova_lista1 = []
nova_lista2 = []

for valor1, valor2 in zip(lista1, lista2):
  if valor1 > 0:
    nova_lista1.append(valor1)
    nova_lista2.append(valor2)
```

O que geraria o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar dentro de um bloco `for` cada elemento da `lista1` e caso o elemento seja maior que zero, ele será adicionado junto com um elemento da `lista2` que tenha sua mesma posição `i`. Veja esse código:

```
lista1 = [2, -1 , 4, -5]
lista2 = [1, 2, 4, 9]

nova_lista1 = []
nova_lista2 = []


i = 0 # Posição do elemento atual

for ele in lista1:

    # Verifica se o elemento é maior que 0
    if ele > 0:
        nova_lista1.append(ele)
        nova_lista2.append(lista2[i])
    i += 1

print(nova_lista1)
print(nova_lista2)
```

Assim como você pode utilizar a função `zip` no bloco `for`. Essa função obtém os elementos de mesma posição em cada iterável e os agrupa em tuplas. Dessa forma podemos substituir a variável `i`. Exemplo:

```
for ele, ele2 in zip(lista1,lista2):

    # Verifica se o elemento é maior que 0
    if ele > 0:
        nova_lista1.append(ele)
        nova_lista2.append(ele2)
```